# Need help in using PredicateBuilder

Tags: sql, linq, predicatebuilder

I need to know about using `PredicateBuilder`. On almost every example of how to use it, they show the code as follows:

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<employee>();

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtAddress.Text))
   predicate = predicate.And(e1 => e1.Address.Contains(txtAddress.Text));
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtEmpId.Text))
    predicate = predicate.And(e1 => e1.Id == Convert.ToInt32(txtEmpId.Text));
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtDesc.Text))
    predicate = predicate.And(e1 => e1.Desc.Contains(txtDesc.Text));
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtName.Text))
    predicate = predicate.And(e1 => e1.Name.Contains(txtName.Text));

EmployeeDataContext edb= new EmployeeDataContext();
var emp = edb.Employees.Where(predicate);
grdEmployee.DataSource = emp.ToList();
grdEmployee.DataBind();
```

What is that `Employee` object, the one between the greater than and less than brackets? I have racked my brains on that one. I am using Linq to SQL entities and I get compile errors when I try this myself. I think the errors are something like:

> *"Cannot cast from a Linq table to..."*

I am a beginner. Please forgive me for asking what may be an obvious thing. Thank you.

Comment: Those `<...>` are called generics, i don't know how to use linq but maby this helps: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546142.aspx

Answer (score 2):

As @MatsRietdijk stated in the comments section, this is generics being used. Basically, with generics you can create a method that will operate on a type/class ("employee" in this instance) that is unknown (although you can control this with the [`where` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6b0scde8.aspx)).

If you were to change the `employee` type for some other type (e.g. `customer`), then the properties available in the [lambda expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) would also be different, based upon whatever properties were publically exposed. For example:

```cs
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<customer>();

// There is no "CustomerName" property from employee, but there is for customer objects
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtName.Text))
    predicate = predicate.And(e1 => e1.CustomerName.Contains(txtName.Text));
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I forgot that point. I'll try it. Also, thank you MatsReitdijk for the link. thanks again.